# O que fazer quando identificar perguntas de trabalho escolar?

Tags: debate

No site em inglês, existe um guia que se aplica a perguntas escolares:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Como já tem aparecido bastante questões desse tipo, gostaria de saber qual é a posição da comunidade StackOverflow em Português.

Acho que os próprios estudantes não compreendem como eles deveriam se portar.

Comment: Acho que deveríamos utilizar a mesma abordagem do SO. Traduzir o post e colocar em um FAQ.

Answer (score 9):

Quando vejo uma questão na qual o perguntador apenas copiou o seu trabalho e o colou na questão sem o mínimo esforço (muitas vezes sem nem mesmo formular uma pergunta), voto imediatamente para fechar como "não está claro o que está perguntando".

Mas havendo algum esforço por parte da pessoa de formular uma pergunta clara e que possa ser respondida diretamente sem fazer o trabalho todo por ele, a questão é válida e deve ser tratada como qualquer outra.

O mais importante para que uma pergunta desse tipo seja aceita, é que se demonstre o que foi tentado e o resultado obtido/esperado. O perguntador deve ter conhecimento suficiente sobre o tema para ser capaz de formular uma pergunta clara.

Comment: Colocar que a questão não está clara não me parece que seria a forma mais canônica. Estou longe de dizer que você está errado. Mas digo que não é a interface não oferece uma solução clara para sinalizar o problema.
A respeito de responder como uma outra resposta qualquer considere que,  segundo a comunidade stackoverflow, é mais saudável ter boas explicações sobre problemas do que soluções muito específicas.

Comment: Eu, é claro, adicionaria um comentário (se um não já existir) explicando o motivo do voto para o fechamento e pedindo mais detalhes e soluções tentadas. Mas não acho que seja possível dar uma resposta boa para uma questão que meramente copie e cole um dever de casa.

Comment: Eu geralmente faço o que eu fazia em fóruns de programação, ou seja, eu vejo se o cara tentou algo, se sim, eu tento ver onde está o problema e sinalizo pro cara através do comentário, aí se ele tentar resolver a partir dali aí sim eu dou prosseguimento, caso contrário eu nem tento responder, pq já sei que é malandragem pra fazer os outros resolverem o trabalho da faculdade pra eles